# Aiming for higher quality images on Facebook page

Tags: facebook, images

The compression Facebook puts on my profile photo (a logo) for my Facebook Page is killing me. I've tried different sizes, png, jpgs, and it always gets pixelated / blurred.

Anyone have experience with getting better results? be it certain colors, compressions, sizes, etc.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and the original photo you are trying to upload?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried "uploading in high resolution"?

It helps a lot when I use it :) Also, the maximum supported resolution is - I believe - 1680 * 1050. Else it will be resized.

You can also download the picture, the quality is generally better. (the link is somewhere below the picture when theatre mode is on).

Comment: Do you have a source for the statement that the max. supported size before FB resizes it is 1680*1050? I realise this is a few years old, and from my understanding Facebook resizes and compresses virtually every picture that is uploaded.

Comment: @Hashim I found this out back then, by uploading differently sized pictures until facebook started resizing them. Nowadays facebook handles much higher resolution images.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to inspect how exactly you are exporting your photo from your photo editing application. It does not necessarily have to be a huge file as there is a maximum width and height.

For example facebook.com/facebook page

[image: Facebook Page Logo]

Layout: 280 x 280
Size: 6,997 bytes

Though there are only three colours used here.
So you many want to also check how many colours you are using.

In the past (very long time), I used to have trouble uploading transparent PNG files, so I would recommend staying with JPG and make sure your program is set to optimize for web viewing. Maybe try uploading the original photo first. Also ensure your resolution is around 72 ppi.